# Java - SSL trouble

Tags: java, ssl, rsa, sha1

Sorry for the uninformative title, but the question is too large to express in a few words.
So, I have a Java program that connects to an SSL webserver using HttpsURLConnection. With the following line in (JDK path)/jre/lib/security/java.security:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2
```

It gives the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints
```

And when I replace it with this line:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=
```

It connects. Now, common logic tells that this is caused by the server using MD2 to sign its certificate. But it doesn't use MD2, it uses SHA1! I have confirmed this by 
1) checking the certificate info from Chrome (the lock button in the address bar -> Connection -> Certificate information)
and 2) running the following code from http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/get-ssl-certificate-info-in-java/ :

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection
.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();

System.out.println("Creating a SSL Socket For "+hostname+" on port "+port);

SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(hostname, port);

/**
* Starts an SSL handshake on this connection. Common reasons include a
* need to use new encryption keys, to change cipher suites, or to
* initiate a new session. To force complete reauthentication, the
* current session could be invalidated before starting this handshake.
* If data has already been sent on the connection, it continues to flow
* during this handshake. When the handshake completes, this will be
* signaled with an event. This method is synchronous for the initial
* handshake on a connection and returns when the negotiated handshake
* is complete. Some protocols may not support multiple handshakes on an
* existing socket and may throw an IOException.
*/

socket.startHandshake();
System.out.println("Handshaking Complete");

/**
* Retrieve the server's certificate chain
*
* Returns the identity of the peer which was established as part of
* defining the session. Note: This method can be used only when using
* certificate-based cipher suites; using it with non-certificate-based
* cipher suites, such as Kerberos, will throw an
* SSLPeerUnverifiedException.
*
*
* Returns: an ordered array of peer certificates, with the peer's own
* certificate first followed by any certificate authorities.
*/
Certificate[] serverCerts = socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
System.out.println("Retreived Server's Certificate Chain");

System.out.println(serverCerts.length + " Certifcates Found\n\n\n");
for (int i = 0; i < serverCerts.length; i++) {
    Certificate myCert = serverCerts[i];
    System.out.println("====Certificate:" + (i+1) + "====");
    System.out.println("-Public Key-\n" + myCert.getPublicKey());
    System.out.println("-Certificate Type-\n " + myCert.getType());

    System.out.println();
}

socket.close();
```

This output the following:

```
    run:
Creating a SSL Socket For 127.0.0.1 on port 5001
Handshaking Complete
Retreived Server's Certificate Chain
4 Certifcates Found



====Certificate:1====
-Public Key-
Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: <first RSA public key>
  public exponent: 65537
-Certificate Type-
 X.509

====Certificate:2====
-Public Key-
Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: <second RSA public key>
  public exponent: 65537
-Certificate Type-
 X.509

====Certificate:3====
-Public Key-
Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: <third RSA public key>
  public exponent: 65537
-Certificate Type-
 X.509

====Certificate:4====
-Public Key-
Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: <fourth RSA public key>
  public exponent: 65537
-Certificate Type-
 X.509
```

I've omitted the actual keys, but the output clearly states that the public keys  are in perfect order and are definetely NOT MD2, but (I think) RSA-encrypted SHA1.

Now, my question is... how is that even possible? Why does disabling MD2 make Java refuse to access a site with an SHA-1 signed certificate? And how in the world can I make my program access the site WITHOUT having to edit the java.security file?

Comment: Run the following comment to check for md2 `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server:port | grep -i md2`

Comment: When the server sends its certificate it has to provide a new digital signature over the certificate plus a few other things, to prove it owns the certificate. This is different from the signature in the certificate itself.

Comment: @jdiver: this command returned the following: 
`depth=3 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
`

Comment: @EJP: thanks, but how does this relate to my question? am I missing something?

Comment: It relates to your question because you're disabling a cipher suite, which controls what the server can do in creating the second signature I mentioned, but the evidence you're producing is all about the first signature I mentioned.

Comment: The public key *in* a cert being RSA (and no hash involved at all) is unrelated to the signature *on* the cert. Look instead at `X509Certificate.getSigAlgName()` or if needed `getSigAlgOID()`. `openssl s_client -showcerts` displays all the certs, but in PEM (encoded) format. To look for fields or attributes within them, such as here an MD2-based sigalg, you need to edit each `----BEGIN...` ... `-----END...` group into a separate file and run it through `openssl x509 -text` and `grep` output from *that*.

Comment: Also @EJP the server signs part of the handshake only for DHE or ECDHE keyexchange, not for RSA keyexchange, and for an RSA key (e.g. DHE-auth-by-RSA) it uses a special combined MD5/SHA1 hash defined by SSL/TLS, never MD2. (For RSA the PoP is implicit in the Finished.)

Comment: The output shows nothing at all about the hash function used to sign the certificates themselves.

Comment: @GregS: it shows that the certificate uses RSA keys, which, as far as I know, are not used with MD2-signed certificates.

Comment: @Mints97: No. RSA plus a hash function is used in the signing algorithm. Evidently one of the certificates is signed with RSA-MD2, probably one of the self-signed root certificates.

Comment: @GregS: running the command `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server:port | grep -i md2` gave me the following output: `depth=3 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain verify return:0` I think this confirms that MD2 wasn't present =)

Comment: No, it doesn't confirm any such thing. It doesn't provide any information about signing algorithms at all. But it's hard to see why it printed anything at all if MD2 wasn't in the output somewhere. You seem to have left something out. @GregS seems to be on the right track here.